# Leaky bathroom faucet - can't find screw on handle

Tags: leak, faucet, sink

Hoping to get help with fixing a leaky faucet in my bathroom. It is dripping at about a drop per second. The water is cold, so I believe it is the cold handle that is the issue (is that an appropriate assumption?)

I was watching YouTube videos for assistance and the first step seems always to remove the handle to investigate the issue. The immediate problem is that I can't figure out how to remove the handle. I do not see a screw anywhere and I cannot find the type or model of the faucet. Below are some pictures. Any advice?

[image: cold handle]

[image: under sink]

Thank you.

Comment: Presumably the button on the end of the handle pries off. Examine what's in there and proceed. Or the end of the handle might unscrew.

Comment: Often a section of the faucet below the handle itself may unscrew. Try holding the handle steady and gripping the bulbous area below the handle and rotating counterclockwise. It could even be the flange at the bottom of the handle.

Comment: 'bib' is correct.  This may be the Moen 4570 faucet.  See the 5:00 mark of this video showing how it goes back on (just do the opposite, lol) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IKXxTfQV3Ng

Answer (score 1):

grab the round base right below the handle that turns the water on and twist ccw to   unscrew the faucet. this is a moen faucet. however, I have the same faucet in my bathroom. I called moen for parts and they said that most parts are not available since they discontinued production of this faucet. iF YOU ARE THE ORIGINAL OWNER of the faucet and can prove it they will send you a new faucet at no charge if the parts needed are not available.

Comment: it is hard to unscrew the bubble of the faucet so sometimes you have to use a wrench and towel